# Why is .Trash-0 using up so much space?

Tags: trash

I want to know why it is using so much space and why what is there is hidden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm thinking that is your trash can. If you open nautilus, right click the trash bin, and hit empty trash, its size should substantially decrease.

Of course, I'm assuming it's a folder. Am I right, or is it a regular file?

EDIT:

Less than a minute of googling later, I believe my answer is right. Optionally, delete it from the command line. But first, educate yourself and read through the top few links in this google search:

http://www.google.com/search?q=.trash-0

```
rm -rf .Trash-0/
```

Comment: Agree to what djeikyb said, there could be files in Trash can which is not deleted yet. If you like to delete any file permanently then do a SHIFT+DELETE

Comment: ahh, i see, guess i never ever, noticed that lol

Comment: Haha, I remember being pretty confused when first using Mandrake, being used to `rm`, deleting things in Nautilus (or whatever it was back then) didn't free up any space.. BTW, I think SHIFT+DELETE works in Windows too.

Comment: Yes SHIFT+DELETE works in Windows as well, a good command and very destructive like "rm -Rf" :)

Comment: Uri, did this work for you?

Comment: yeah, i marked tha answer as accepted yesterday O_O but it didn't show properly